# Pointer to multi-dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I don't know what's the problem with this piece of code, I'm just getting a random result here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main() {
    char arr[3][2] = {{'z','a'},{'e','r'},{'x','v'}};
    int i;
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("%c",*(arr+i));
    getch();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What do you expect `*(arr+i)` to produce?

Comment: When I give "i" the value 0 it needs to print 'z' , value "1" it needs to print 'a' ...etc

Comment: OT: Not what I call "Memory safe code" by the way. /OT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is not clear what you are trying to do.
I can only suggest to change statement

```
printf("%c",*(arr+i));
```

the following way

```
printf("%c",**(arr+i));
```

In this case if i will be in the range 0 - 2 then this statement will output the first character of the corresponding row. For example for i equal tp 1 the output will be

```
e
```

if you want to output any character in the array using i as an index then use

```
printf("%c", *( *arr + i ));
```

Or

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) printf("%c", *( *arr + i ));
```

Comment: What if I want to print 'a' ?

Comment: @JohnnyCat Then you would enter the value `0` for `i` and do `*(*(arr + i) + 1)` or `arr[i][1]`.

Comment: I guess arr is a pointer to the whole array and *arr is a pointer to the first row. That's why when we use **(arr+i) it will access the first element of the "i" row.

Comment: @JohnnyCat In expressions arr has type char ( * )[2] that is pointer to char [2]. *arr means the array char[2] In expressions it is converted to char * So the expression *arr + i has type char *

Comment: Maybe you wanted `arr[i/2][i%2]` . Using the `*(+)` notation seems more confusing than `[][]` to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the value `0` then it will give the result assign the address of zero-th item 
and if you provide the `1` it will print the address of 1st item

```
zero-th item  = {'z','a'},
first item = {'e','r'}
```

it will print the address of these above 2 item using format specifier `%c` , here you are trying the to print the address `%c` instead of `%u`.